# Sorting linked list struct by count property in C (read in via text file in Ubuntu)

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I wrote a speech analysis program that reads in a speech(via the redirect to stdin in ubuntu, not analyzing somebody's voice, but analyzing a text file of a speech), stores the word and the number of occurrences in a linked list struct. I am trying to get my program to only output the top 10 words with the most occurrences (both the word and the number of occurrences)  but I cannot figure out how sort my linked list. My code works as far as counting and outputting all of the words with their counts, but like I said I only need the top 10 words with their count values. I will post my whole program, and screenshot of the partial output as it prints out currently.

This is how it looks after my program runs. I just need the top ten in a format like:

```
able 8
together 7
little 3
etc....
```

[image]

Sorry if the code is a bit slopping. I couldn't get it to format when I copied it in here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 31
#define MAX_TEXT_LENGTH 10000
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

// keeps track of word and count
struct WordCount {
    char* word;
    int word_count;
    struct WordCount* next; // pointer to next word
};

// functions
void addWord(char* pWord); // adds or updates words
int isDelim(char ch); // looks for delimeters
void show(struct WordCount* pWordcount); // prints word and count
struct WordCount* createWordCount(char* word); // creates new struct
void makeLower(char* input);

// global var
struct WordCount* pStart = NULL; // pointer to first word counter in list

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char text[MAX_TEXT_LENGTH]; // stores text read in
    char buffer[MAX_WORD_LENGTH]; // holds a single word
    size_t i = 0; // index of text
    int len = 0; // length of word
    struct WordCount* count = NULL; // pointer to word count

    if (argc < 1) // checks for atleast 1 argument
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Arguments needed.\n");
        return 1;
    } else // has at least 1 argument
    {
        while (fgets(text, MAX_TEXT_LENGTH, stdin) != '\0') // read from stdin
        {
            i = 0;
            makeLower(text); // turns all letters to lower
            while (text[i] != '\0') // now get the words
            {

                while (isDelim(text[i])) // skip the delimeters
                    ++i;
                // while (isShort(text[i])) //trying to skip over short words
                //++i;

                len = 0; // reset count of length of word
                while (
                    (!isDelim(text[i])) &&
                    (text[i] != '\0')) // make sure not     delim and not '\0'
                    buffer[len++] = text[i++];
                if (len > 2) // make sure len of word is greater than 0
                {
                    buffer[len] = '\0'; // append '\0' to end of word
                    addWord(buffer); // add word to struct
                }
            }
        }
        /* List the words and their counts */
        count = pStart;
        while (count != NULL) {
            show(count);
            count = count->next;
        }
        printf("\n");

        // free memory
        count = pStart;
        while (count != NULL) {
            free(count->word); // free space for the word
            pStart = count; // save address of current
            count = count->next; // move to next counter
            free(pStart); // free space for current
        }
    }
    return 0; // success
}

// returs true if delim, false if not
int isDelim(char ch) {
    static char delims[] = {' ', '\n', '"', ',', '.', ':', '?', '!', '/', '-'};
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(delims); i++) {
        if (ch == delims[i])
            return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

// prints words and count
void show(struct WordCount* w) {
    printf("\n%s %d", w->word, w->word_count); // print
}

// add word to list or update count
void addWord(char* word) {
    struct WordCount* count = NULL;
    struct WordCount* pLast = NULL;

    if (pStart == NULL) {
        pStart = createWordCount(word);
        return;
    }

    // if the word is in the list increment count
    count = pStart;
    while (count != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(word, count->word) == 0) {
            ++count->word_count;
            return;
        }
        pLast = count; // link it in list
        count = count->next; // move pointer
    }
    // word not accounted for, add to list
    pLast->next = createWordCount(word);
}

void makeLower(char* c) {
    while (*c != '\0') // while not '\0'
    {
        *c = tolower(*c); // convert to lowercase;
        c++; // move to next
    }
}

// create and return a new WordCount struct
struct WordCount* createWordCount(char* word) {
    struct WordCount* count = NULL;
    count = (struct WordCount*)malloc(sizeof(struct WordCount));
    count->word = (char*)malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(count->word, word);
    count->word_count = 1;
    count->next = NULL;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a linked list? They are a huge pain to sort.

Comment: How is it that I do not believe that a person that is able to write a speech analysis program is unable to program a sorting algorithm. Something does not ring true here.

Comment: @Ed Heal He specializes only on speech analysis. Sorting algorithms is not his specialization.:)

Comment: Easiest way to sort a linked list: 1) create an array of pointers that point to the elements of the linked list 2) sort the array of pointers using `qsort` 3) recreate the linked list from the array of sorted pointers.

Comment: I am new at programming C. I usually program in C# or Java. I am sorry @Ed Heal that I cannot figure out how to sort a linked list. It took me nearly a month to get what I have here.  I am using a linked list only because it is the only thing I have been able to get to work.

Comment: @ksudood - But you managed to write a speech analysis program ?!

Comment: @EdHeal Yes I did. It just puts the words in a linked list and increments a count if it is there and adds it if it isn't. It doesn't do anymore than that.

Comment: Doesn't speech analysis involve lots of maths, searching for patterns. Converting sound into text?!

Comment: No I am reading in a text file from stdin. I'm not taking in the sound. I posted the code to my whole program in my question.  I'm doing this via the terminal in Ubuntu:             ./myfile < textfile.txt

Comment: WRT your `isDelim()` function: take a look at the standard library functions `strspn()` and `strcspn()` They exist for a reason.

Comment: Ehh, mergesort: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8962397/905902 (shameless self-promotion alert)

Answer (score 0):

in c, where we don't have dynamic arrays, I find a liked list easier to sort.

There are many sorting algorithms, bubble sort is a good one to start with. If you google bubble sort you will find many code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a fixed-size window (10), you could build an array of the first 10 entries, noting the least count in the group.  Then, for each remaining item, if it has a greater count than the least in the top 10, replace that least entry and find the new least entry.  At the end, you'll have the top 10 ready to sort.

That's O(n) with at most 10 compares per entry (after the first 10, one to see if it the new entry replaces a previous one and 9 more to find the new low entry),  The average should be about 5.5 comparisons per entry, since the probability of replacement moves linearly from nearly 1 to nearly 0 in a long list.  (1+10)/2 average between best and worst cases is 5.5.

This code will be about the same in any language that can define a 10-element array.

Unless you need the rest of the list sorted for some reason, there's no reason to write a linked-list sort, and the array sort at the end is already written (`qsort()` from `<stdlib.h>`.) You just have to write a comparison function.

---

ETA: I just noticed an apparent error in your `add_word()` function.  You update the last entry pointer to point to a new entry with:

```
pLast->next = createWordCount(word);
```

...but then you don't update pLast to point to this new entry.  It looks like you need to add `pLast = pLast->next;` after that statement.

By the way, that logic is O(NM) where N is the number of unique words and M is the number of word occurrences.  If you have lots of text, this could be quite slow.  A hash table approach may be worth the extra code.